# Is it secure to generate a new address using SBC such as raspberry pi? any problem with TRNG?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, coldstorage, raspberry-pi, random

I am trying to create a cold wallet using SBC such as raspberry pi (not raspberry pi).

I wonder if the random generator is secure enough to generate random wallet address, for both BTC and ETH.

I heard there were fatal flaw in Android random number generator before. Is it possible that SBC can have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

The TRNG in every modern rPi is indeed quality high entropy

/dev/hwrng "seeds" (feed extra entropy to) the /dev/urandom device

Take a look in the /var/log/syslog file

need rng-tools.service running

apt policy rng-tools

Also check haveged is in the kernel.

Good overview here

https://hackaday.com/2017/11/02/what-is-entropy-and-how-do-i-get-more-of-it

Also check out Easyseed https://github.com/nym-zone/easyseed

Use an rPi with no networking hardware, ideally wipe it securely between sessions.